# Compiler does not warn about precision loss?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-warnings

I have been playing around with C++11 lately, and came up with the following sum function:

```
template <typename T>
inline T sum(const std::function<T (int)> &f, int initial, int end)
{
    T retval = 0;
    for(int k = initial; k <= end; k++) {
        retval += f(k);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

The idea is that I can pass a lambda function and thus have a neat and readable function for mathematical sums. I then tried the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<double, 2> arr1 = {{ 0.5, 1.5 }},
                          arr2 = {{ 1.5, -0.5 }};
    auto n = sum<int>([&](int k) { return arr1[k]*arr2[k]; }, // Precision loss!
                      0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using g++ 4.6.3: `g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -o test main.cpp` and does not give any warning about the precision loss I remarked in the comment of the source code.

It's pretty much a given here that `sum<int>` is a bad thing to do, but it might not be that obvious in more complex contexts. Should the compiler not notice that return value of my lambda function is `double` and warn me that I am losing out on precision when casting to `int`? Is there a specific reason it does not?

Comment: The function will not be aware of the precision becasue the runtime does an implicit cast before passing in the arguments. You'r right though, in an ideal world you should at least see a warning in visual studio / your IDE to reflect that this would result in precision loss. but isn't this type of thing what unit tests are about?

Comment: @Wardy in an ideal world it wouldn't compile (i.e. it would be an error, not a warning) without an explicit request to cause this precision loss.

Comment: ok ... well im a C# developer and i have to go by the rules of .net (not sure if you are also using a .net compiler but) it states in the documentation that where a less precise type is expected an implicit cast is applied ... it's considered to be a feature of the language. I agree though ... an error would be the absolute dream in your scenario but not common to the platform in my experience.

Comment: Note that `-Wall` is not "all", you should use `-Wall -Wextra`. `-pedantic` is a silly a bit, I guess.

Comment: VS2010 produces the anticipated warning (warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data)

Comment: @user396672: Then again, [VC2010 implements a pre-standard version of lambda's](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572138)

Comment: @MSalters: yes, but the problem is rather inside std::function. I replaced lamda with free function: double instead_of_lambda(int k)
{ return (arr1[k]*arr2[k]); } // (arrays arr also moved into global scope). This issus the same warning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems entirely reasonable. You're telling the compiler not to bother with Template Argument Deduction (i.e. use `sum<double>`) but instead tell it explicitly to use `sum<int>`. That's as good as an explicit cast.

[Edit] What about

```
template <typename F>
auto sum(F const& f, int initial, int end) -> decltype(f(initial))
{
    auto retval = f(initial++);
    while(initial <= end) {
        retval += f(initial++);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: It is strange enough if warnings concerning statements in the function _implementation_ depend on a _way_ in which template arguments have been deduced

Comment: @user396672: Which "function implementation" are you referring to? There's no statement in `sum<int>(const std::function<int (int)> &f, ...)` which warrants a warning.

Comment: return (implicit cast to int) arr1[k]*arr2[k];

Comment: @user396672: But that's a lambda expression. The type of its `operator()` is `double (unnamed-type::*)(int)`, so you wouldn't get a warning for that `return` either.

Comment: I agree with your argumentation, though it's not like I had a choice: the template argument deduction does not work here (at least not using g++).

Comment: @nijansen The specification for `std::function` doesn't allow for template argument deduction to work. You're misusing `std::function` in this instance. (Unfortunately I don't have a handy link for a pre-canned summary of when to use and when to *not* use `std::function`.)

Comment: @nijansen: It doesn't, because lambda's can only be _converted_ to `std::function<T>`. If they _were_ objects of type `std::function<T>`, it would work. But the compiler won't go on a wild goose chase to find possible conversions for TAD. It only tries to find the exact `T`.

Comment: @MSalters: sorry, my mistake; the implicit conversion is actually performed inside std::function implementation

Answer (score 2):

VS11 does issue a warning:

Warning 1   warning C4189: 'n' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
**Warning   2   warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data**

Edit, actually that warning is from using the code:

```
template <typename T,typename Func>
inline T sum(Func f, int initial, int end)
```

You get a different warning about the bad conversion if you use `std::function<T (int)>`, so VS is still good on this issue. (IMO, you should generally take functors as a templated type rather than std::function)

Even clang with -Weverything doesn't issue a warning about this (Edit: although I can't test the std::function version with clang ATM). Seems like something that could be improved.

I do get this strange warning though:

```
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:15:51: warning: will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    auto n = sum<int>([&](int k) { return arr1[k]*arr2[k]; }, // Precision loss!
                                                  ^~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

If you unconstrain the functor and if you change the line `retval += f(k);` to `retval += T { f(k) };` in the following way:

```
// Machinery to allow caller to indifferently use
// sum(f, i, j) and sum<R>(f, i, j)
struct deduced {};

template<
    typename Request = deduced
    , typename Functor
    , typename Ret = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_same<Request, deduced>::value
        , typename std::result_of<Functor&(int)>::type
        , Request
    >::type
>
inline Ret sum(Functor f, int initial, int end)
{
    Ret retval = 0;
    for(int k = initial; k <= end; k++) {
        retval += Ret { f(k) };
    }
    return retval;
}
```

then instead of relying on the compiler's willingness to warn, you make it *required* to emit a diagnostic as a narrowing conversion is disallowed within list-initialization (i.e. initialization with braces).

I don't think there's a reliable way if you constrain the functor to an `std::function<Sig>`. That depends solely on how the implementation wrote `std::function`, when it issues warnings for narrowing conversions, and even whether it warns for its own code.